# Need help creating a mass email program

Tags: php, email

New to the forum but love the comments. I'm tech savvy but not when it comes to programming, coding etc. So - I guess that makes me tech stupid for the moment.

Basically - I want to create a mass email program that will allow us to send bulk emails to our customers who signed an email slip. Currently - we're at 100,000 or so in our database but we expect to see this rise to 200,000 at some point.

What is the best script language to use for this? 
Is PHP going to be handle this many emails? 
What is the most emails that I can send in any one batch for it to still be "safe" so that the emails arrive to the proper recipients?
What is the term when you send directly from the server?

We currently have 3 servers and I'm assuming they are capable of doing this no problem...but I haven't spoken to our webhosting company just yet.

Lastly - I put together a powerpoint...that gives specs - is there anyone here that would be interested in a little side work to do the project? Really interested in the feedback. Thanks.

Comment: If you have money, but not a technical team, you should really hire out the whole thing--not to a developer, but to a company that sends email as a business.

Comment: If you don't have money or a technical team, you probably shouldn't be sending so much email...

Comment: At the end of the day - it comes down to doing the smart thing...doing the thing where we spend the least amount of money for a certain acceptable quality of work.  

Companies that send emails as a business are mucho, mucho expensive.  And its not that we can't afford it necessarily but...its wasted money.  Its money spent that can not be spent on another area.  I have spoken to enough developers by now....that its just a matter of finding the right person for this job.  But - a 3rd party option is always an option....whatever ends up saving money for the right quality of work.

Comment: Deleted the "user-interface" tag, since this question is not UI related.

Comment: The only one I have experience with is: http://www.phplist.com/

Answer (score 8):

In general and based off what you said -- **do not create your own mass email program**.

Use a service, such as MailChimp or iContact.

Here's a small list of some of the things they do for you:

1. Manage the list
2. Handle unsubscriptions
3. Handle soft bounced emails
4. Handle hard bounced emails
5. Handle white listing (You have to pay third party companies $$$s a month to be on these lists)
6. Give you an idea of how likely and spammy your email is
7. How fast your email can be sent out (AOL will put you on their blacklist if you send out too fast)
8. Handle Analytics (such as how many were opened, when, where, what links were clicked on, linking to Google Analytics)
9. Handle multiple lists and variable replacement (such as "Dear _____")
10. Nice, easy-to-use interface.

Again, that's a small list in the scheme of things. Those were off the top of my head without too much thought.

---

EDIT

A couple big advantages I didn't mention:

**a) Support**
**b) A community**
**c) Constant improvements**
**d) No server-management**

Comment: You all have my thanks - we're looking at both options....whether its to go with our own server or to go with a different service.  There are many reasons why we would use a third party but there are also great reasons to create our own....even though there are challenges to that as well.  But the comments were helpful and the thought process was easy to follow.

Comment: Go with this answer. Mass emailing is full of subtle gotchas that can bite you hard. Do it badly and you can see your company blacklisted as a a spammer, and that is a whole world of pain.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1.  Acquire a real email server.
Step 2.  Utilize said email server by having your scripts send the mail to it for delivery, and not directly.
Step 3.  Throttle the mail server as necessary
Step 4.  Monitor the non-delivery reports and remove addresses as necessary...

Answer (score -2):

It depends on how you do this. You can:

1) loop and send 100 000 individual mail

2) Send 1 email with 100 000 people in BCC

or mix both. php can handle it well, but it's a huge task on the mail server.